# How do I make big.mark apply to more than just the first column?

Tags: r, pander

Here's what I'm getting:

```
> panderOptions('big.mark', ',')
> foo <- rbind(cancer, cancer); for(i in 1:8) foo <- rbind(foo, foo)
> pander(table(foo$ph.karno, foo$pat.karno))

-----------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;    30    40   50   60   70   80    90    100 
--------- ----- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----- ----- -----
 **50**     0   512  512  512  512   512    0     0  

 **60**     0   512  512  2560 4608 1536    0     0  

 **70**   1,024  0   1024 4608 3072 3072  1536  1536 

 **80**     0    0    0   6144 6656 6656  10240 4608 

 **90**     0    0    0   1536 5120 10752 12288 7680 

 **100**    0    0    0    0   512  3584  6656  4096 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I would like the comma delimiter to show up in the other columns too. How do I do that?

Comment: This was a bug in the package that I've [just fixed](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/96a262fd350493988433b996eb2affac1f697a6c), so the most recent version of `pander` installed from GH should work as expected. If you find any similar issues, please feel free to open a ticket directly on GH -- the chance that I bump into the problem is lot higher that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best result I got (with t being your `table` call result):

```
> pander(format(t,big.mark=','))

----------------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;    30    40   50    60    70     80     90    100 
--------- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----- ------ ------ -----
 **50**     0   512   512   512   512   512     0      0  

 **60**     0   512   512  2,560 4,608 1,536    0      0  

 **70**   1,024  0   1,024 4,608 3,072 3,072  1,536  1,536

 **80**     0    0     0   6,144 6,656 6,656  10,240 4,608

 **90**     0    0     0   1,536 5,120 10,752 12,288 7,680

 **100**    0    0     0     0    512  3,584  6,656  4,096
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I assume this is a bug in `pander.table.return` but I did not dig enough to get the root cause.

Edit: I found the reason, line 283 of the function there's a for loop calling `sapply` on each col, but once the first column has been processed, the full array of the table is converted to char as we bring in chars from the output of `format`.

Then the subsequent calls to `format` can't format the number as they've been coerced to char.

Code from `pander.table.return` giving this behavior:

```
for (j in 1:ncol(t)) {
  temp.t[, j] <- sapply(temp.t[, j], format, trim = TRUE, 
                        digits = digits[j], decimal.mark = decimal.mark, 
                        big.mark = big.mark)
}
```

Comment: The diagnosis is correct :) I've just pushed a [commit](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/96a262fd350493988433b996eb2affac1f697a6c), to fix this.

Comment: @daroczig great :) Sorry I've been too lazy to search the github repo and open and issue.